# MySQL query for weighted voting - how to calculate with values assigned to different columns

Tags: mysql

I have a voting application that writes values to a mysql db table. It is a preference/weighted voting system so people choose a first option, second option, and third option. These all go into separate fields in the table. I'm looking for a way to write a query that will assign numerical values to the responses (3 for a first response, 2 for a second, 1 for a first) and then display the value with the summed score. I've been able to do this for total number of votes

```
select count(name) as votes,name 
from (select 1st_option as name from votes 
      union all 
      select 2nd_option from votes 
      union all 
      select 3rd_option from votes) as tbl 
group by name 
having count(name) > 0 
order by 1 desc;
```

but haven't quite figured out how to assign values to response in each column and then pull them together. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your voting system is called "borda count" and is regarded as very vulnerable for strategic voting, by the way. Is your database-design fixed? Can you show your tables? Seems as if it was not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select sum(score) as votes,name 
from (select 1st_option as name, 3 as score from votes 
      union all 
      select 2nd_option as name, 2 as score from votes 
      union all 
      select 3rd_option as name, 1 as score from votes) as tbl 
group by name;
```